# Spring @ExceptionHandler doesnt handle error

Tags: java, spring, error-handling, converters

I have a class like

```
@RestController
public class CustomerRestController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerManagementService customerManagementService;

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    @ExceptionHandler(CustomerNotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ClinetErrorInformation> rulesForCustomerNotFound() {

        ClinetErrorInformation clinetErrorInformation = new ClinetErrorInformation("Clinet was not found");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(clinetErrorInformation, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/customer/{id}"})
    public Customer requestCustomerById(@PathVariable String id) throws CustomerNotFoundException  {
        return customerManagementService.findCustomerById(id);
    }

}
```

The exception is not handled by the class:

```
Severe:   com.mycompany.crmproject.services.customer.CustomerNotFoundException
at 
...
com.mycompany.crmproject.restcontroller.CustomerRestController.requestCustomerById(CustomerRestController.java:44)
```

Dispatcher Servlet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.crmproject.restcontroller"/>


    <mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager"/>
    
    <bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false"/>
        
        <property name="favorParameter" value="true"/>
        
        <property name="parameterName" value="mediaType"/>
        
        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="json" value="application/json"></entry>
                <entry key="xml" value="application/xml"></entry>               
            </map>
        </property>
        
        <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="false"/>
        
    </bean>

</beans>
```

What maybe the reason why this error isn't handled and in the browesr I can only see blank page.

Http Response

```
Status Code: 200 OK
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 02 Mar 2017 14:09:52 GMT
Server: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.1 JSP/2.3 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8)
```

Pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>CRMProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <name>CRMProject</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Draft-16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>10.13.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
            <version>10.13.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: You config looks good, I cannot reproduce your issue in Tomcat. Can you show your pom? Can you try using a different web container?

Comment: @artemisian I have uploaded pom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the exception is being thrown? Looks like service returns null and this is what you see.

Comment: Yes I am:
Severe: com.mycompany.crmproject.services.customer.CustomerNotFoundException at ... com.mycompany.crmproject.restcontroller.CustomerRestController.requestCustomerById(CustomerRestController.java:44)

Comment: This is just log message, could it be that the exception is logged and swallowed?

Comment: Exception was handled by aop proxy, Thx for help

Answer (score 0):

Add `@ResponseBody` to your exception handler method. With `@RestController` only the `@RequestMapping` methods use`@ResponseBody` by default.

---

Maybe you have another exception resolver registered. Change the priority for `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver`.

If you use annotation configuration:

```
@Bean
public ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver exceptionHandlerExceptionResolver()         
{
  ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver exceptionHandlerExceptionResolver = new ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver();
  exceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.setOrder(1);
  return exceptionHandlerExceptionResolver;
}
```

If you use xml configuration:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver">
    <property name="order" value="1"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: added ResponseBody annotation but it didn't make a difference.